# Is there any way to access a method from another in module object?

Tags: javascript

```js
// module.js
module.exports = {
    m1() {
        console.log('m1')
    },
    m2() {
        this.m1()
        console.log('m2')
    }
}
// index.js
const { m2 } = require('./module')
m2()
```

When I try to access a method from another in a module object, it gives the following error: `TypeError: this.m1 is not a function`. I have tried this on a normal object dozen of times yet never seen an error like that. Is this an error special to the `module` object? If so, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: No, this happens on any other object whose methods use `this` as well. Use `module.m2()` instead of destructuring, or call `module.exports.m1()` inside `m2` instead of referring to `this`.